# Can't retrieve friend's album in Android/Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to retrieve a friend's albums with the following code. Both the account I'm logged in and the one whose albums I'm trying to get are Test Users, so permissions shouldn't be an issue. I retrieve selectedUsers with a friend picker. But eventually i get this error,

```
12-18 02:18:32.969: D/error(4182): {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: AaJHRMAiukD_rQWiC-K_RXMEjTWzGjJO-dx6QwonppGEcaNlUL4YKLn80pepf-pXHkrgVNYnPktnH25czlD5eIhkXrtlFN8qQZB1UhhXPEAgAA}
```

as well as a NullPointerException at getInnerJSONObject line.

```
   String grPath = "/"+selectedUsers.get(0).getId()+"/albums";
   RequestAsyncTask req = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),grPath,null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                if(null != response.getError()){

                    Log.d("error", response.getError().toString());

                }

                GraphObject responseGraphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                JSONObject json = responseGraphObject.getInnerJSONObject();

                        try {

                            JSONArray jarr = json.getJSONArray("data");

                            for(int i =0;i<jarr.length();i++){

                                String name= jarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");


                                String albid= jarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                          }
                      } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();

                    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't permissions be an issue just because it is a test user? You have to ask the test user for permission

Comment: Is it the "friends_photos" permission that I need to ask?

Comment: That only exists in v1.0. You need to ask the test user for user_photos

Comment: I checked it with getActiveSession().getPermissions(), I have user_photos permission. It must be sth else.

Comment: I'm suspecting what getID returns in grPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create your app after 4/30/2014? If so, you're on version 2.x of the Graph API, and you can no longer get the photos of a friend. You can only access the photos of the user who has logged in and authorized your app. This is what @WizKid was referencing.

What you're seeing from selectedUsers.get(0).getID is from the taggable_friends endpoint, which gives you a one-time, obfuscated String id, and you should not try to use it for anything other than to tag friends (like when you're uploading a photo).

Comment: Yes, I created the app after 4/30/2014. So, there is no way to get friend albums anymore then. Thanks.