# Facebook getID() returning String instead of an Integer

Tags: android, facebook

When I'm using getID with the Graph User I'm logged in with, it returns 1384180348541924 which works fine in the subsequent Request graphPath. But when I do the same with a friend's graph user (test user) as below

```
String grPath = "/"+selectedUsers.get(0).asMap().get("id")+"/albums";
```

it returns something like this as ID:

```
AaJGpNTVFmsHEysoUVpRMX7DEUSSyqKkwGbsm-q6ZZBudLw0y3eG9L4saB6AHr5-bxH3QVsKo8Z1Q9bGf0rkNhzFUJ0x165PLrwToK3kXiBhDg
```

What might be the reason?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[In facebook reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/interface/GraphUser/#getId) you can see what graph user id is a string. Why you waiting int?

Comment: Because when I use that ID to retrieve friend albums I get this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537245/cant-retrieve-friends-album-in-android-facebook

Comment: See my answer to your other question. You should only use this ID for tagging friends, and nothing else.